# adding an fstab option using Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, mount, mount-point

I am trying to add nodev to my `/etc/fstab` file. I am using the Ansible command below but with no luck. My issue lies with the regular expression, I'm not a pro at regex.

```
- name: Add nodev to /etc/fstab
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/fstab
    backup=yes
    backrefs=yes
    state=present
    regexp='(^/dev[\w/_-]+(\s+(?!nodev)[\w,]+)*)'
    line='\1,nodev'
```

One of the lines from `/etc/fstab` that I am trying to add `nodev` is:

```
/dev/mapper/ex_sys-ex_home /home /ext4 rw,exec,auto,nouser,sync 1 2
```

Comment: Define "no luck". What was the actual result? I'm guessing that /etc/fstab was unchanged, instead of adding "nodev" to some lines?

Comment: @LarsH will provide results here in a second, I modified the regexp to (^/dev[\w/_-]+\s+/[\w/_-]+\s+/[\w/_-]+\s+((?!nodev)[\w,]+)*) and I think that might work

Comment: Yeah, I think the fact that you had `\s+` in your repeating group for the options was blocking the match. Let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: The regexp before was adding nodev to a swap drive(one of the one's I didn't want it to be added to)....applying the new regex doesn't modify anything. Removing the \s+ only added it to one of the mapper drives(at the end of the string, not where it needed to go)

Answer (score 27):

While this may not be the most elegant answer, it worked for me.

```
- name: Ensure fstab uses nodev
  mount:
    name: "{{ item.mount }}"
    src: "{{ item.device }}"
    fstype: "{{ item.fstype }}"
    opts: "{{ item.options }},nodev"
    state: present
  with_items: ansible_mounts
  when: item.options.find(",") >= 0 and item.options.find("nodev") == -1
```

Comment: Actually I find it very nice and concise.

Comment: Thanks For this

I needed to only edit some mount paths, so I added a list (mnt_paths) of the paths. and then added additional conditional to say when `item.mount in mnt_paths` to be more targeted.

Comment: Not sure if this depends on the version but  in ansible 2.4.2.0 I have to use `with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"` instead.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it may incorporate temporary mounts into the static `/etc/fstab`, and also it will change some items for the less stable variants, like *UUID* references into dynamic `/dev/mapper/*` paths

Comment: I made too changes.  The first one is the same as comment from Bram above. `with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"`  and second is to add `when: item.mount == "/" and item.options.find(",") >= 0 and item.options.find("nodev") == -1`

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Joe's answer I made this version which will add a single option to a specific line in `/etc/fstab` if it isn't there already. This will also keep any other options the line already had.

main.yml

```
- import_tasks: fstab-opt-present.yml point=/home opt=nodev
```

fstab-opt-present.yml

```
- name: '/etc/fstab: Set opt "{{ opt }}" for mount point {{ point }}'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/fstab
    backup: yes
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^(\S+\s+{{ point }}\s+\S+\s+)(?!(?:\S*,)?{{ opt }}(?:,\S*)?\s+)(\S+)(\s+.+)$'
    line: '\1{{ opt }},\2\3'
  register: fstab

- name: 'If {{ point }} changed, remount'
  command: 'mount {{ point }} -o remount'
  when: fstab.changed
```

https://regex101.com/ is a really helpful tool for building and testing these kind of regexps. Just enable the "multiline" option there and open the "Substitution" panel and you can even paste in your `/etc/fstab` and see which lines your regex will match and what it will do to them. Just remember to use real values instead of the Ansible variables `{{ point }}` etc. when testing there

Comment: `validate: "mount -fav -T%s"` is a nice option to add. It basically does a dry run of `mount -a` for the new file.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to state that there seems to be a new ansible module which covers all this much more easily:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 3):

We've developed a 3rd-party ansible module to add, set or remove mount options. Check it out!

```
  - mountopts:
      name: /
      option: nodev
```

https://github.com/Uberspace/ansible-mountopts

Answer (score 2):

Tested & works fine

```
- name: Set  nodev option
  replace:
    path: /etc/fstab
    backup: yes
    regexp: '^(\S+\s+)(\/\S+)(\s+)((?:ext4|xfs)\s+)(?!(?:\S*,)?nodev(?:,\S*)?\s+)(\S+)(\s+.+)$'
    replace: '\1\2 \4 \5,nodev \6'
```

It excludes adding nodev to /(root), sets only to ext4 and xfs filesystem. doesn't add to  temp filesystems.

Note: while you test regexp101, make sure to select python

Answer (score 0):

Landed here looking for an answer, wound up rolling my own for my use case:

main.yml

```
- include: fstab-opts.yml point=/tmp opts=noexec,nodev,nosuid,noatime
- include: fstab-opts.yml point=/backup opts=noatime
```

fstab-opts.yml

```
---

- name: 'Ensure {{ point }} flags'
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/fstab
    # uses "(not-spaces spaces /tmp spaces )(not-spaces)(the rest)" pattern to match column content and capture args
    regexp: '^([^ ]+[ ]+\{{ point }}[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+)([^ ]+)(.*)'
    line: '\1{{ opts }}\3'
    backrefs: yes
  register: fstab

- name: 'If {{ point }} changed, remount'
  command: mount -o remount {{ point }}
  when: fstab.changed
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added the noexec,nodev,nosuid option in /etc/fstab for the /var/tmp mount point.

Requirement is:

1. Ensure noexec option set on /var/tmp partition
2. Ensure nodev option set on /var/tmp partition
3. Ensure nosuid option set on /var/tmp partition

if required install ansible.posix.mount module using below command .

```
# ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

Playbook:

```
---
 - name: "STEP 1: Get /var/tmp mounted SRC device"
   shell: mount | grep -E '\s/var/tmp\s' | awk '{print $1}'
   register: "vartmpsrc"

 - debug:
     msg: "Validated the /var/tmp mount output: {{ vartmpsrc.stdout }}"

 - name: "Add mount noexec,nodev,nosuid options for /var/tmp"
   mount:
     path: "/var/tmp"
     src: "{{ vartmpsrc.stdout }}"
     fstype: "tmpfs"
     opts: "nosuid,nodev,noexec"
     state: "present"
   when: vartmpsrc.stdout == "/var/tmp"

 - name: Remount /var/tmp mounted volume with mount options noexec,nodev,nosuid
   ansible.posix.mount:
    path: /var/tmp
    state: remounted
   when: vartmpsrc.stdout == "/var/tmp"

 - name: 'STEP 2: Validate noexec,nodev,nosuid option set on /var/tmp partition'
   shell: mount | grep -E '\s/var/tmp\s' | grep -v {{ item }}
   loop:
    - noexec
    - nodev
    - nosuid
   register: vartmp_exists
   ignore_errors: yes
   when: vartmpsrc.stdout == "/var/tmp"
```